# Created multiple instances of the same image using a loop, can I move each instance of the image independently?

Tags: python, pygame

I have an image in pygame with multiple instances of the image called in a for loop. is there a way I could move each instance of the image independently without moving the others with the code as is? or will I have to load separate instances of the image individually?

```
def pawn(self): 
    y_pos = 100
    self.image = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('pawn.png'), (100,100))
    for x_pos in range(0,8,1):
        pieceNum = x_pos
        screen.blit(self.image, (x_pos*100, y_pos))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to use [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) and [`pygame.sprite.Group`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group):

Create a class derived from `pygame.sprite.Sprite`:

```py
class MySprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, image, pos_x, pos_y):
        super().__init__() 
        self.image = image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.topleft = (pos_x, pos_y)
```

Load the image

```py
image = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('pawn.png'), (100,100))
```

Create a list of sprites

```py
imageList = [MySprite(image, x_pos*100, 100) for x_pos in range(0,8,1)]
```

and create a sprite group:

```py
group = pygame.sprite.Group(imageList)
```

The sprites of a group can be drawn by `.draw` (`screen` is the surface created by `pygame.display.set_mode()`):

```py
group.draw(screen)
```

The position of the sprite can be changed by changing the position of the `.rect` property (see [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.move)).

e.g.

```py
imageList[0].rect = imageList[0].rect.move(move_x, move_y)
```

Of course, the movement can be done in a method of class `MySprite`:

e.g.

```py
class MySprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    # [...]

    def move(self, move_x, move_y):
        self.rect = self.rect.move(move_x, move_y)
```

```py
imageList[1].move(0, 100)
```

Comment: Thanks heaps, Really well explained! Much appreciated. :)